# How to strict search attributes in Algolia Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, algolia

[image]

Here is showing `ObjectID`. But I don't want to show this. How to restrict this.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Configuration on the index and define the Searchable attributes you wouldn't be able to search by objectID.